# Django 1.7.2 migrate error (AttributeError)

Tags: django

This is error when run data migration:

```
Running migrations:
  Applying bird_monitoring.0027_auto_20150327_1102...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/.virtualenvs/Client/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 555, in __get__
    rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)
AttributeError: 'Locality' object has no attribute '_owner_cache'

During handling of the above...
```

"Locality" have attribute owner:

```
owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='Owner', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Configuration: Ubuntu, Python 3.4, Django 1.7.2, SQLite

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE:
"Target" model:

```
class CampaignRegistration(models.Model):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, verbose_name='campaign')
    scrutineer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='scrutineer')
    locality = models.ForeignKey(Locality, verbose_name='locality')
```

Migrate code:

```
def transfer_become_scrutineers(apps, schema_editor):

    Campaign = apps.get_model("app", "Campaign")
    Locality = apps.get_model("app", "Locality")
    CampaignRegistration = apps.get_model("app", "CampaignRegistration")

    campaign = Campaign.objects.get(pk=1)

    for locality in Locality.objects.all():
        if locality.owner is None:
            pass
        else:
            registration = CampaignRegistration()
            ...
            registration.save()
```

Comment: Please show the full migration code.

Comment: You might have to add a dependency to your auth user's app.